# WorkFlow type in dropdown property of designs of the listpageForm in AX is not available

Tags: workflow, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am creating a workflow to have someone approve when prospects are made customers.

Could someone please tell me why is query important to have a workflow ? I didnt create a new query as smmBusinessRelations_NoFilter already exists and I am using it.

Also, when I chose to add workflow to the smmBusinessRelationsListPage

I have to change 3 properties in the design menu

Workflow Enabled            :        Yes

WorkflowDatasource        :        smmBusRelTable

WorkflowType                  :        (I Want to chose my workflow type here)

But sadly the drop down doesnt show anything ?

I have checked my workflowtype properties and in its DocumentMenuItem I have chosen smmBusRelTable , I can also choose smmBusinessRelationsListPage not really sure if that changes anything.

Thanks

VB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [the walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc653399.aspx) carefully.

There is also a [slide show](http://www.slideshare.net/murrayfife/creating-custom-workflows-in-dynamics-ax-2012) if you prefer.

Why [create a query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc653399.aspx)?

> Before you create a workflow type, you must first create a query that
>   will access the table fields for the workflow document. The following
>   procedure describes how to create a query that will be used by the
>   workflow type.